# calling a function from a list in python

Tags: python

Take this example:

```
presets = [
    "eggs",
    "bacon"
    ]

print(presets[0])
>>> eggs
```

Why can a not do the same thing, with a list of items to execute? Take this example:

```
from animations import animation_2, animation_3, animation_4
presets = [
    animation_2.iterate(animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final),
    animation_3.iterate(animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final),
    animation_4.iterate(animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final)
    ]
```

When I run this (both WITH and WITHOUT the `preset[n]`) it executes all three commands in the list. Why is this? I would like to have a list of those presets, and call them via am index number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can do **exactly the same thing**, *if* you store the callables and not the result of calling them. Just store e.g. `animation_2.iterate`, then pass the arguments when you take them back *out* of the list.

Comment: Store as `presets = [animation_2.interate, ...]`.  Then call by ..............................................            
 `presets[0](animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final)`

Comment: If you saw `[factorial(4), factorial(5)]` in a program, would you think the first element of that list is a command you can retrieve and execute later, or would you think it's the factorial of 4? Same with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the actual function objects in a list

```
from animations import animation_1, animation_2, animation_3
presets = [
    animation_2.iterate,
    animation_3.iterate,
    animation_4.iterate
    ]
```

Then call the desired function based on its index. This way the function is not executed upon constructing the `list`, rather it is only executed once you call it.

```
presets[0](animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It executes the items because that's what you are telling it to do. Your code is exactly the same as this:

```
p1 = animation_2.iterate(animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final)
p2 = animation_3.iterate(animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final)
p3 = animation_4.iterate(animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final)
presets = [p1, p2, p3]
```

Python has no way of knowing that you didn't intend to call those functions.

One solution is to store a tuple:

```
presets = [
    (animation_2.iterate, animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final),
    (animation_3.iterate, animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final),
    (animation_4.iterate(animations_templates_path, thumbnails_final),
```

]

That stores the function and the arguments without calling the function. You can iterate over the list at a later date and execute the function.

Comment: This is extremely helpful in allowing me to understand what I am doing. However, I am going to mark the other answer as the solution because in my use case, it allow me to write less code and iterate over it easier.